# How to install OpenSSH 8.3 Server on linux?

Tags: software-installation, openssh

I am trying to install OpenSSH 8.3 server on linux. I downloaded the file from https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/ and have done all the steps from [Install openssh-server 8.0p1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544614/install-openssh-server-8-0p1-on-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts) answer. Results:

```
$ ssh -V                    
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
$ sshd -V                    
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
```

Howerver if I try to start ssh server with `sudo service ssh start` I become an error:

```
Failed to start ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.
```

If I install OpenSSH with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` everything works fine. The problem is: I want specific OpenSSH version. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does `sudo service sshd start` work? Note that the service name is `sshd` not `ssh`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon no, I become the same error...

Comment: The startup scrips are located under the contrib directory, you will be expected to sort that part out manually.

Comment: @Bib that means I need to configure some startup scripts in contrib directory? Do you maybe know which of them and how? Thank you!

Comment: There is `openssh-8.3p1/contrib/redhat/sshd.init`. Alter it to suit and, well, just use it.

Comment: @Bib should I then copy this file to /lib/systemd/system direcoroty to add the ssh service?

Comment: Try it and see... You're in experimentation territory. You don't even need to do that as you can just execute it directly regardless of its location. You also do not need it. You can just run the daemon directly with what ever switches it requires. Just try and think about the problem.

Comment: @Bib I started sshd but it says that I have no config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config... I created this file and became another error... I realy do not understand what I should do that's why I am asking here

Comment: There is a default sshd_config in the tarball.

Comment: @Bib I figured it out, thank you!